# Calling OneNote GetHierarchy() from Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, onenote

I have a Silverlight 4 out-of-browser, elevated trust application.  I would like to use the OneNote 2010 object model to communicate with OneNote using the AutomationFactory and I'm not able to get the [GetHierarchy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg649853.aspx) method of the Application to work.  I know I have data in OneNote, because I can call the method from a .NET application and get data back from it.  The GetHierarchy() method returns null.  Any suggestions?

```
class OneNoteAutomation
{
    dynamic oneNote;

    enum HierarchyScope
    {
        hsSelf = 0,
        hsChildren = 1,
        hsNotebooks = 2,
        hsSections = 3,
        hsPages = 4
    }

    public void GetHierarchy()
    {
        if (AutomationFactory.IsAvailable)
        {
            this.oneNote = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("OneNote.Application");

            var result = this.oneNote.GetHierarchy(
                string.Empty, 
                (int)HierarchyScope.hsNotebooks, 1);            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just wanted to check in to see if the below answers your question (unfortunately it doesn't fix the issue, but is the only possible answer right now).

Comment: It's a good answer - I'm just waiting for one that solves my problem.

Comment: I hear ya. I'd be interested in an answer that allows you to use an *out* as well in SL. Unfortunately, I don't believe one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that calls with methods that have 'out' cannot be used in AutomationFactory - please see [SL4 - AutomationFactory - Call method with 'out' parameters raise exception: 'Could not convert an argument for the call to...'](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/588326/sl4-automationfactory-call-method-with-out-parameters-raise-exception-could-not-convert-an-argument-for-the-call-to)

BTW, I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the `1` in your `GetHierarchy` call - that is the pointer to the string that will be filled with the XML of the chosen `HierarchyScope` enum. It should be a string `out` variable, instead of an integer - but regardless, it still won't work in SL4 due to the bug.

Comment: I have confirmed that this is a bug in the Silverlight 4 COM automation marshaller: [out] parameters don't work.